# ReactJS + SSO + SAML + Cognito

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement SSO using SAML federatedSignIn of Cognito. I am looking for better solution. as not any solution is working for me

I tried aws-amplify, aws-amplify-reac etc.

In future I might need to go with other provider so I am considering cognito only.

It's good to have solution which will be effective as much as possible. As I tried all possible ways to configured it.